# Exclude all except one subfolder for Rubocop

Tags: ruby, rubocop

Let's say we have a folder called `bin` and it includes another subfolder `bin/scripts` besides other folders and top-level files.

We are looking to scan only the `bin/scripts/**/*` files and ignore everything else in the `bin` folder.

This pattern bellow excludes everything in that folder

```yaml
AllCops:
  TargetRubyVersion: 3.1.2
  NewCops: enable
  Exclude:
    - "bin/**/*"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use ERB to Template Your Exclusions

This is covered by the RuboCop documentation on [including/excluding files](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/configuration.html#includingexcluding-files) when used in conjunction with the section on [pre-processing](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/configuration.html#pre-processing) using [ERB](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html). There might be a more elegant way to do this, but using ERB to add excluded items based on an inverted regular expression using [Enumerable#grep_v](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep_v) on a [Dir#glob](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Dir.html#method-c-glob) just seems easiest to me.

This was tested with Ruby 3.1.2 and RuboCop v1.30.1, and "just works." Your mileage may vary with other versions or approaches.

```rb
AllCops:
  TargetRubyVersion: 3.1.2
  NewCops: enable
  Exclude:
    <% Dir.glob('bin/**/*').grep_v(%r{bin/scripts/}).each do |path| %>
    - <%= path %>
    <% end %>
```

With the template above in `.rubocop.yml` and a tree structure of:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── bar.rb
│   ├── baz
│   │   └── quux.rb
│   └── scripts
│       └── wuuble
│           └── zub.rb
└── lib
    └── foo.rb
```

RuboCop only checks:

- lib/foo.rb
- bin/scripts/wuuble/zub.rb

Comment:  completely missed this. I have used ERB like this before. Agree, can't think of anything faster than this. `Find` or a combination of `Dir` and `reject`. Probably slower though.